# Redux using functional component without React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, react-functional-component

I have a functional componet without React but that uses Redux like following:

```
export const isAuthenticated = () => ({user}) => {
    console.log("user : ", user);
    return true;
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        user: state.auth.userInfo
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(isAuthenticated as any)
```

And to use above function, I uses like:

```
{isAuthenticated() && (
                        <li className="nav-item">
                            <NavLink
                                className="nav-link"
                                activeStyle={{
                                    color: "#1ebba3"
                                }}
                                to="/dashboard"
                                onClick={(e) => { if (this.menu.classList.contains("show")) { this.inputElement.click() } }}
                            >
                                Dashboard
                            </NavLink>
                        </li>
                    )}
```

It doesn't work. It just doesn't even get into that isAuthenticated function since I don't see any output for `console.log("user : ", user);`. It should output something like `user: undefined`, but it doesn't even output that.

If I change

```
export const isAuthenticated = () => ({user}) => {
```

to

```
export const isAuthenticated = ({user}) => {
```

then the problem is that I can't call it with `isAuthenticated()` and might be duplication between passed param from function call and retrived state from Redux.

How can I fix it if I want to keep using "`isAuthenticated()`" for calling that method, without passing any param, but let Redux pass user state to that function?

Comment: you're probably looking for https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved with React's [Hooks API](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html). What you are aiming for is a custom hook that will internally use [`useSelector`](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector) from `react-redux`. If you don't want to use functional components, you can always opt for [Higher-Order Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) (HOCs)

### Code Samples

#### Custom Hook

```js
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

export function useIsAuthenticated() {
    return useSelector(state => !!state.auth.userInfo);
}

export function YourComponent(props) {
    const isAuthenticated = useIsAuthenticate();

    // Return your react sub-tree here based on `isAuthenticated`
    // instead of `isAuthenticated()` like before.
}
```

#### Higher-Order Components

```js
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export function withIsAuthenticated(Component) {
    function mapStateToProps(state) {
        return {
            isAuthenticated: !!state.auth.userInfo
        };
    }

    return connect(mapStateToProps)(function({ isAuthenticated, ...props }) {
        return <Component isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated} {...props}/>;
    });
}

export function YourComponent({ isAuthenticated, ...props }) {
    // Return your react sub-tree here based on `isAuthenticated`
    // instead of `isAuthenticated()` like before.
}
```

### Opinion

Personally, I feel that HOCs introduce a lot more complexity than necessary, and if I'm not mistaken, this was one of the primary drivers behind the creation of the Hooks API.